# Popup Issue in the Firefox browser only

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, popup, alert

When I call API with Async Await function. And then after I open the link in the new tab that time gave alert.

> Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window.

my code is in Javascript.

How to bypass this alert or how to remove this alert ?

This is the demo :

```js
$("a#link").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = this.href;

  // this will not be blocked
  var w0 = window.open(url);
  console.log("w0: " + !!w0); // w0: true

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    // this will be blocked
    var w1 = window.open(url);
    console.log("w1: " + !!w1); // w1: false
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
```

Anyone can help me for this ?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?  Like jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @RajKamal, check demo

Answer (score 1):

> How to bypass this alert or how to remove this alert ?

There's no way to do that. It's by design.

from [Firefox 65 release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/65#DOM_events)

> Going forward, only one Window.open() call is allowed per event (bug 675574).

and [an official blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/01/firefox-65-webp-flexbox-inspector-new-tooling/)

> Lastly, to avoid popup spam, Window.open() may now only be called once per user interaction event.

Here's a Minimal, Reproducible Example

```js
document.onclick = function() {
  window.open("https://stackoverflow.com") // a click opens this
  window.open("https://superuser.com")     // but not this, one-action, one-window
}
```